# Showing that a function composed of two other continuous functions is continuous

Tags: real-analysis, solution-verification

I have a function

$$g'(x) = f'(x) - 3g(x)$$

and want to prove that $g'(x)$ is continuous on the interval $[0, 1]$.

I know that $f$ is $C^1$ on the real numbers, and thus $f'$ is continuous, and I know that $g$ is continuous on the interval $[0, 1]$.

Thus, for the interval $[0, 1]$, we know $\forall \epsilon > 0$, there is $\delta_1$ that satisfies the definition of continuity for $f'$, and there is $\delta_2$ that satisfies the definition of continuity for $g$.

Then, using triangle inequality, I can show that $\delta = \min\{\delta_1, \delta_2\}$ satisfies the definition of continuity for $g'$ - is this the way to approach the problem?

Comment: Your on the good track keep going, the way to do so is by using the definition of continuity for the two functions $f$ and $g$, then some small manipulations

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, that is a way to go. For any $c\in[0,1]$, we have

\begin{align*}
\forall\varepsilon>0, \exists\delta_1>0\text{ such that }0<|x-c|<\delta_1&\implies|f'(x)-f'(c)|<\frac\varepsilon2\\
\forall\varepsilon>0, \exists\delta_2>0\text{ such that }0<|x-c|<\delta_2&\implies|g(x)-g(c)|<\frac\varepsilon6\\
\end{align*}

Set $\delta=\min\{\delta_1,\delta_2\}$, as you mentioned. Then the above statements still hold.

Now, let $\varepsilon>0$ and suppose $0<|x-c|<\delta$. Then

\begin{align*}
|(f'(x)-3g(x))-(f'(c)-3g(c))|&=|(f'(x)-f'(c))-(3g(x)-3g(c))|\\
&\le|f'(x)-f'(c)|+3|g(x)-g(c)|\\
&<\frac\varepsilon2+3\cdot\frac\varepsilon6\\
&=\varepsilon.
\end{align*}
Therefore, $g'(x)$ is continuous on $[0,1]$.

Answer (score 0):

I already replied to you in the comments, but another way to do it is, we know that a function $f$ is continuous at a point $x_0$, if whenever a sequence $a_n$ converges to $x_0$, we have $f(a_n)$ converges to $f(x_0)$.

Now let $x_0\in [0,1]$, then $\forall$ sequence $a_n$ such that they converge to $x_0$, we have $f'(a_n)$ and $g(a_n)$ both converge to $x_n$. Can you take it from here?